# How to share TypeScript code between truffle tests?

Tags: solidity, constructor

I have some code in my TypeScript tests, say:

```
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}
```

which I'd like to share with all my tests. The simple solution is to copy the function into each *_test.ts file.

How can I "import" this code from `foo_test_helper.ts` in a truffle test?

If possible, I'd like to avoid adding Babel to my build. It should work with a project created by `npx truffle init`. If you suggest Babel, then please include (pointers to) the instructions necessary to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

Recipe:

1. Create a file `foo.ts` in the `test/` folder (next to the other tests).
2. At the bottom of the file, add:

   ```
   module.exports = {
       foo: foo // export function foo() defined above as "foo"
   };
   ```
3. Import the function in your other tests:

   ```
   const { foo } = require('./foo.ts');
   ```

If you need to export more functions, add the names to the `exports` object and list them in the `require()` assignment, separated by commas. Order is not important, the variables will be matched by name.